# Deploy the source by war at Tomcat, must restart the server when change the html?

Tags: java, html, tomcat, war

The project is deploy by WAR at Tomcat 8, when I change the page.html, after save refresh the web page, I can't see the change, only restart the server.

Is there any way to solve this problem that I can see the change and no need restart the server?

Deploy by WAR must restart the server?

I'd like to thank you for your help.

Comment: hi all， thank you for answered this question.

Comment: this question has been solved.
add below message into spring-mvc.xml 
<bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver"> 
<property name="cacheable" value="false"/>
</bean>
disable the cacheble.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying your web application as WAR containing static resources such as HTML pages, CSS and JS, I don't think you can update these files without restarting your container because these resources are inside the WAR.

So when you update these resources, you need to repackage your WAR and then Tomcat needs this new WAR and restart the container.

Please note that Tomcat can restart a container without restarting the whole server:

From [Tomcat Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server):

> ### Deploying on a running Tomcat server
>
> It is possible to deploy web applications to a running Tomcat server.
>
> If the Host `autoDeploy` attribute is "true", the Host will attempt to
>   deploy and update web applications dynamically, as needed, for example
>   if a new .WAR is dropped into the `appBase`. For this to work, the
>   Host needs to have background processing enabled which is the default
>   configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you just see the old version of the content from the browser cache. Try reloading the page with ctrl-f5 to force a cache refresh after deploying the war.